# Will natty be distributed still on a cd?

Tags: 11.04

I read that on Natty if Unity is not be supported  by my hardware Ubuntu install a desktop like Maverick.

Can, Unity and Gnome, stay together on a cd or Ubuntu will be on a dvd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plan is to ship Natty on a CD. However, the addition of Unity, GTK3 and Banshee means that other aspects of the CD footprint need to be optimized, so that it can still fit on to a CD.

There is a blueprint which is driving this work: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/performance-desktop-n-install-footprint. Some things which might be removed from the CD include upstream changelogs and Perl

Comment: I think that now 99% of people has a dvd reader into their PCs, why Ubuntu can be distribuited into a dvd for the normal users and into a small cd version for the users with old PCs.

Comment: @Matteo: there is a DVD version already

Comment: 1% is a lot - of 10 million users that would be 10,000 people who couldn't get Ubuntu!

Comment: @Maco with language packs not so? I think most of us agree on a slim version and a fully packed version of some sort. One for Ubuntu and one for Kubuntu. Xubuntu should be a CD only until XFCE gets heavier.

Comment: @fluteflute: of 10 million that'd be 100,000

Comment: @Roland: Yes most of the space is taken up by additional language packs, but there are more software packages as well.  What's installed by default is the same, but you can use the DVD as a repository to get more.

Comment: See also: [Why doesn't Ubuntu move to DVDs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10148/why-doesnt-ubuntu-move-to-dvds)

Comment: Won't Banshee just replace Rhythmbox rather than take up additional space?

Answer (score 6):

I spoke with Martin Pitt about this specific issue at UDS last week.

Yes, CD's will still be the primary distribution media for Natty.  There is already a DVD version with additional software, but the development team considers the CD important.  Many users download the distro as an ISO; DVD ISOs take a lot longer to download.  Martin also shared his opinion that the space limitation of the CD forces the team to be efficient and selective in what they include, keeping the distro lean and mean.

I've heard proposals rather than a DVD image, to move to a 1G usb stick type of distribution.  However, Martin has further ideas on how to cut more fat out of our existing stuff (like dropping changelogs in packages, trimming down what all's included with open office, and so on), so I think until all those ideas are exhausted we won't see ubuntu changing the standard target media type.

(Personally, I favor the idea of having a 'core' cd and an 'applications' cd, but I think I may be alone in this opinion.)

Comment: I assume/hope the idea would be to only drop the changelogs from the CD media? I actually would like to see a 'core' and 'applications' CD, if that would mean I could also perform a sort of netinstall with just the 'core' CD.